# Displaying a graph by coordinates using text mode

Tags: c#

For the function Y = f(X), display the Y values for X = 0, 0.25, 0.5, ... 19.75. Get a graph of a function on the screen using text mode. I was able to calculate the Y values and display the corresponding table. But I don’t understand how to build a graph, it turns out that it is displayed in a mirror, and not as I need, as I understand it, you need to put a '-' sign in the line `y = (Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 1, 2)) - 1);` , but then nothing is displayed in that location. Please tell me how to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, y; 

        Console.WriteLine("|   x   |   y   |");

        double maxY = Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(1 - 1, 2)) - 1;

        for (x = 0; x <= 4; x += 0.20)
        {

            if (x < 2)
            {
                y = (Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 1, 2)) - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                y = -0.5 * Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 3, 2));
            }

            Console.Write($"| {x,5:F2} | {y + 1,5:F2} |");

            PrintGraph(maxY, y);

            Console.WriteLine();
        } 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }  

    static void PrintGraph(double maxY, double y)
    {
        StringBuilder graphLine = new StringBuilder("          ");  
        int h = (int)((y + 1) * 10);

        if (h >= 0 && h < 10)
        {
            graphLine[9 - h] = '*'; 
        }

        Console.Write(graphLine);
    }
}
```

The schedule need

[image]

And the one I have

[image]

Comment: The issue is the WriteLine().  You need to write all the y values with same value and then add the return character with WriteLine().  So you first need to sort the y values in descending order.

Comment: Is the graph to be displayed on its side, with 0 value after the table and 1 value to the right by 10 spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

A few points to make.

- The functions were not correct, and inconsistent between the two arcs. I moved them into separate functions. The function `TwoArcs` combines the two arcs to the desired output. The function `OneArc` defines the upper half of an arc, but scaled to a specific maximum y value (so half an ellipse really).

  ```
  y = y_max * √(1 - ((x-center)/radius)^2)
  ```
- The evaluation of maximum y was incorrect
- The `WriteLine(.. ,{y+1, ..)` in the display of values is erroneous as you should not change the value `y` that is printed compared to what is used.
- Your range of `x` values `0..4` was incorrect. If you look at the graph the second arc spans `2..3`.
- Certain values of `x` can produce `NaN` and I fixed that with defaulting  to `0` in `TwoArcs()` when not in range.
- Your output graph was mirror because you use `9-h` instead of `h` for designating the column where a `*` is placed.

Fixing the above yields the following output

```text
|   x   |   y   |
|  0.00 |  0.00 |*
|  0.17 |  0.55 |     *
|  0.33 |  0.75 |       *
|  0.50 |  0.87 |        *
|  0.67 |  0.94 |         *
|  0.83 |  0.99 |         *
|  1.00 |  1.00 |
|  1.17 |  0.99 |         *
|  1.33 |  0.94 |         *
|  1.50 |  0.87 |        *
|  1.67 |  0.75 |       *
|  1.83 |  0.55 |     *
|  2.00 |  0.00 |*
|  2.17 |  0.37 |   *
|  2.33 |  0.47 |    *
|  2.50 |  0.50 |     *
|  2.67 |  0.47 |    *
|  2.83 |  0.37 |   *
|  3.00 |  0.00 |*
```

my source code is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, y;

        Console.WriteLine("|   x   |   y   |");

        double maxY = 1.0;

        for (x = 0; x <= 3; x += 1.0/6)
        {
            y = TwoArcs(x);

            Console.Write($"| {x,5:F2} | {y,5:F2} |");

            PrintGraph(maxY, y);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static double HalfArc(double x, double x_min, double x_max, double y_max)
    {
        if (x <= x_min || x >= x_max) return 0;
        double x_cen = (x_max + x_min) / 2, radius = (x_max - x_min) / 2;
        return y_max * Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow((x - x_cen) / radius, 2));
    }

    private static double TwoArcs(double x)
    {
        double y = 0.0;
        if (x <= 2.0)
        {
            y = HalfArc(x, x_min: 0.0, x_max: 2.0, y_max: 1.0);
        }
        else if(x <= 3.0)
        {
            y = HalfArc(x, x_min: 2.0, x_max: 3.0, y_max: 0.5);
        }

        return y;
    }

    static void PrintGraph(double maxY, double y)
    {
        const int width = 10;
        StringBuilder graphLine = new StringBuilder(new string(' ', width));
        int h = (int)((y / maxY) * width);

        if (h >= 0 && h < width)
        {
            graphLine[h] = '*';
        }

        Console.Write(graphLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("|   x   |   y   |");
      for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
      {
        double y;
        double x = i / 10.0;
        if (x<=2.0) {
          y = Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x-1, 2));
        }
        else {
          y = Math.Sqrt(0.25 - Math.Pow(x-2.5, 2));
        }
        if (Double.IsNaN(y)) {
          y = 0;
        }
        Console.Write($"| {x,5:F2} | {y,5:F2} |");
        Console.Write(new String(' ', (int)(y*10)));
        Console.WriteLine("*");
      } 
  }
```

Producing:

```
|   x   |   y   |
|  0.00 |  0.00 |*
|  0.10 |  0.44 |    *
|  0.20 |  0.60 |     *
|  0.30 |  0.71 |       *
|  0.40 |  0.80 |        *
|  0.50 |  0.87 |        *
|  0.60 |  0.92 |         *
|  0.70 |  0.95 |         *
|  0.80 |  0.98 |         *
|  0.90 |  0.99 |         *
|  1.00 |  1.00 |          *
|  1.10 |  0.99 |         *
|  1.20 |  0.98 |         *
|  1.30 |  0.95 |         *
|  1.40 |  0.92 |         *
|  1.50 |  0.87 |        *
|  1.60 |  0.80 |       *
|  1.70 |  0.71 |       *
|  1.80 |  0.60 |     *
|  1.90 |  0.44 |    *
|  2.00 |  0.00 |*
|  2.10 |  0.30 |   *
|  2.20 |  0.40 |    *
|  2.30 |  0.46 |    *
|  2.40 |  0.49 |    *
|  2.50 |  0.50 |     *
|  2.60 |  0.49 |    *
|  2.70 |  0.46 |    *
|  2.80 |  0.40 |    *
|  2.90 |  0.30 |   *
|  3.00 |  0.00 |*
```